# If data attribute is true with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with my code. I am trying to add a background color to div if data attribute is true. This is my HTML code:

```
<html data-highcontrast-applied="true">
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="row-centered">
    <p>
    Helllllllooooooooooo
    </p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is jQuery code

```
$(document ).ready(function() {

        if(typeof $("html").attr('highcontrast-applied')  == 'true')
        {
            $(".row-centered").css({"background-color": "red"});
        }

    });
```

Can somebody help me with this? Also this is a jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/dmv9o3ep/2/

Comment: either use `$("html").attr('data-highcontrast-applied')` or `$("html").data('highcontrast-applied')` So you final `if` statement would be `if($("html").data('highcontrast-applied'))`

Answer (score 2):

try to remove typeof and get the value of this attribute like string then compare it with 'true'

```
$(document ).ready(function() {

    if($("html").attr('data-highcontrast-applied').toString() == 'true')
    {
        $(".row-centered").css({"background-color": "red"});
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

The problems with your code are:

1. You are not properly getting the value of the html attribute;
2. `typeof` on `$("html").attr('data-highcontrast-applied')` will return `boolean` not the value of the html attribute;

I would set the data-* attribute to either `1` or `0` and then use `parseInt` and check if it's equal to `1` and apply the background (or any other css properties you want):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (parseInt($("html").attr('data-highcontrast-applied')) === 1) {
    $(".row-centered").css({
      "background-color": "red"
    });
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/eht9faoz/

You can read more about jQuery `.data()` and `.attr()`:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7262427/867418

Answer (score 0):

You misspelled the attribute name, try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if(typeof $("html").attr("data-highcontrast-applied"))
    {
        $(".row-centered").css({"background-color": "red"});
    }   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to use `typeof` there

```
$(function() {
        if($("html").data('highcontrast-applied') == true) {
            $(".row-centered").css({"background-color": "red"});
        }
 });
```

this works like this

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
if($("html").attr('data-highcontrast-applied')){}
```

or

```
if($("html").data('highcontrast-applied')){}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use native javascript to achieve

```
$(document ).ready(function() {
        var temp = document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].getAttribute("data-highcontrast-applied");
    console.log("temp==", temp);
        if(temp === 'true')
        {
            $(".row-centered").css({"background-color": "red"});
        }

    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tyfg6ezv/

Answer (score 0):

You can try with .addClass().It's working.

```js
$(document ).ready(function() {
  var temp = document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].getAttribute("data-highcontrast-applied");
  if(temp === 'true')
  {
   $(".row-centered").addClass("intro");
  }
 
 });
```

```css
.intro{
  background-color : red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html data-highcontrast-applied="true">
<head>

</head>
<body>
  <div class="row-centered">
    <p>
    Helllllllooooooooooo
    </p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```